# How to add a node in BST?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have tried the following algorithm by using recursion but the nodes are not getting appended to the tree.  Please tell me what's wrong.

```
void search_add(struct node *t)
{
    if(t==NULL)
    {
        t = newNode(temp->key);
        return;
    }
    else if(t->key>temp->key)
    {
        search_add(t->right);
    }
    else if (t->key<temp->key)
    {
        search_add(t->left);
    }
}

void insert(struct node *node, int key)
{
    temp = newNode(key);
    search_add(node);
}

int main(void)
{
    root = newNode(50); 
    insert(root,30);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t = newNode(temp->key);` is only changing the local copy passed, which is then forgotten, and the caller's `t->right` or `t->left` remains `NULL`.

Comment: There are *thousands* of duplicates of this problem on this site. Unfortunately, the mistake is generally made by beginners and the titles/texts of the questions so-divergent they're difficult to actually find. `t = newNode(temp->key);` does *nothing* to the *caller's* passed in argument. It is a local variable as far as the function is concerned. All this ultimately ends up doing is leaking memory. [Example duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188313/why-is-my-bst-root-pointer-changing-for-some-unknown-reason).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: temp is  a global variable .

Comment: @WhozCraig , how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as already stated byWeather Vave, is:

> `t = newNode(temp->key);` is only changing the local copy passed,
>   which is then forgotten, and the caller's `t->right` or `t->left`
>   remains NULL.

A solution could be to change this:

```
void search_add(struct node *t)
```

to this:

```
void search_add(struct node *t)
```

Of course, then use `*t` inside the body of the function, instead of `t`.

That way you are passing a double pointer, which will make changes visible outside of the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning any value in your recursion .Please try below code I am a java so please ignore any syntax issue.

```
/* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);   

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
```